# jquery validation on 2 radio boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have jquery to validate attendance however it is not working at present. I have 2 attendance radio groups named attendance1 and attendance2 the form is called list.

```
    $("input[name=attendance1]:checked").triggerHandler('click'); 
    $("input[name=attendance2]:checked").triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: if you fix the indentation and brackets in your code, you will see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if is not working because $("input[name=attendance1]:checked") returns a jquery object not matter what. If it is not checked, then it will return an empty jquery object. is() method will return true or false:

```
   $("#list").submit(function() {
        console.log("submitted");
    if ($("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {
               alert('Please select attendance1');
        if ($("input[name=attendance2]").is(":checked")) {
              alert('Please select attendance2');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

EDIT: (if statement logic was wrong) (and edited again to simplify further)

```
  $("#list").submit(function() {
    console.log("submitted");
return 0 == $("input[name^=attendance][value=Yes]").not(":checked").each(function(){
              alert('Please select ' + $(this).attr('name'));
    }).length;
});​
```

Comment: Your if-statement logic is wrong then... I will edit my post to fix that for you.

Comment: Okay here you go. Please note that now you will get two alerts if neither is checked, which is not really user-friendly. Best thing is to replace the alert by appending the message to the fields label.

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working as you can see in the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ay7uy/1/

Comment: Oh I see you are using radios... I was expecting checkboxes although u said radios...

Comment: can you see: http://jsfiddle.net/Ay7uy/5/ and view the jquery script tags and see if im doing it right as it works in jsfiddle but not online :s. jquery.js is in my root

Comment: if jquery is in your root, they you should put its url as /jquery.js and not just jquery.js.

Comment: hmm ok but it is still not working when upload to web server :S

Comment: Well that is down to some other issue now. It has nothing to do with your original question anymore. I suggest that you post another question for that, with some more details.

Comment: Different issue -> ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
$("#list").submit(function() {
    console.log("submitted");
    if (!$("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select attendance1');
    }
    if (!$("input[name=attendance2]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select attendance2');
        return false;
    }
});
```